# Honeycomb webview ontouchmove events

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

We're listening for 'ontouchmove' in the webview in an Android app.  These events seem to come over fine in 2.3, but on Honeycomb, it seems like we get one event fired and that's it.  Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

The code samples in my answer are gwt samples, but the same should hold for JavaScript.

The WebView will take over the event after the first `onTouchMove` mainly in order to allow scrolling. You can prevent this with a call to

```
event.preventDefault();
```

I don't know why this especially is a Honeycomb thing, but if you catch the first `onTouchMove` event and decide at this point if you want to take over by calling `preventDefault()` you should be able to handle many cases. As an example, I wanted to implement horizontal swiping whilst still allowing basic functionality (like vertical scrolling, links, ...) to work.

```
    @Override
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
    case Event.ONTOUCHSTART:
        startPoint = new Point(event.getChangedTouches().get(0).getClientX(), event.getChangedTouches().get(0).getClientY());
        break;
    case Event.ONTOUCHMOVE:
        endPoint = new Point(event.getChangedTouches().get(0).getClientX(), event.getChangedTouches().get(0).getClientY());
        double dx = startPoint.getX() - endPoint.getX();
        double dy = startPoint.getY() - endPoint.getY();
        if (Math.abs(dx) > SWIPE_X_MIN) {
            if (Math.abs(dy) < SWIPE_Y_MAX) {
                // Decided it really is a horizontal swipe
                event.preventDefault();
                if (dx < 0) {
                    Window.alert("swiped right");
                } else {
                    Window.alert("swiped left");
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }       
}
```

I hope that gives some insight.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

I'm using GWT and implementing a feature which needs the touch move event handling. Your solution works for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

preventDefault on touchstart will allow the events to fire, but native scrolling will be disabled... (less than ideal!) There is a shim that attempts to overcome this issue that is embedded on millions of android devices.
https://github.com/TNT-RoX/android-swipe-shim